# Zeppelin download link?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have installed Zeppelin but incubator is not there. What is the link to download Zeppelin which could be integrated with cloudera?
I have tried downloading the zeppelin through this link http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html
and also by git link 
https://github.com/apache/zeppelin
but when i downloaded and tried with both the versions still the incubator is missing. Please let me know the proper procedure to download zeppelin and how to integrate it with cloudera. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.7.2/zeppelin-0.7.2-bin-all.tgz

Comment: Could you try that one? I could download successfully by the download link.

Comment: I tried from this link only but after installing it is not showing incubator folder. Can you help me with installing and running it with cloudera.

Comment: just before the maven clean step. Thanks for the response

Comment: What is the incubator folder? AFAIK, the downloaded file is tar.gz and you can extract the zeppelin files. Then, run `${ZEPPELIN_HOME}/zeppelin-daemon.sh start` (in case of linux, mac)

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you so much. And i'm trying to integrate it with cloudera.